# PhraseQuery+Lucene 4.6 is not working for PDF Word search

Tags: pdf, lucene

Iam Using lucene 4.6 version with Phrase Query for searching the words from PDF. Below is my code. Here Iam able to get the out put text from the PDF also getting the query as                                  contents:"Following are the". But No.of hits is showing as 0. Any suggestions on it?? Thanks in advance.

```
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);

            // Store the index in memory:               
            Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
            // To store an index on disk, use this instead:
            //Directory directory = FSDirectory.open("/tmp/testindex");
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46, analyzer);
            IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
            iwriter.deleteAll();
            iwriter.commit();
            Document doc = new Document();
            PDDocument document = null;
                try {
                    document = PDDocument.load(strFilepath);
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Exception Occured while Loading the document: " + ex);
                }
              String output=new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
              System.out.println(output);
            //String text = "This is the text to be indexed";
            doc.add(new Field("contents", output, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
            iwriter.addDocument(doc);
            iwriter.close();

            // Now search the index
            DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
            IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
            String sentence = "Following are the";
            //IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
            if(output.contains(sentence)){
                System.out.println("");
            }

           PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
            String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
               query.add(new Term("contents", word));
            }

            ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;
            // Iterate through the results:
            if(hits.length>0){
                System.out.println("Searched text existed in the PDF.");
            }
            ireader.close();
            directory.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
         }
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the right code? Your `sentence` is `"2.3"` which you `.split(" ")` and then use as the phrase query argument. This makes little sense.

Comment: sorry for the confusion ..the sentence here is "Following are the"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why your `PhraseQuery` is not working

1. [`StandardAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) uses `ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET` which contains *a, an, and, are, as, at, be, but, by, for, if, in, into, is, it, no, not, of, on, or, such, that, the, their, then, there, these, they, this, to, was, will, with* these words which will be removed from [`TokenStream`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html?is-external=true) while indexing. That means when you search "Following are the" in index, **are** and **the** will not be found. so you will never get any result for such a `PhraseQuery` as **are** and **the** will never be there in first place to search with.
   Solution for this is use this constructor for
   `Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);` while indexing this will make sure that [`StopFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/StopFilter.html) will not remove any word from `TokenStream` while indexing.
2. `StandardAnalyzer` also uses [`LowerCaseFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/LowerCaseFilter.html) that means all tokens will be normalized to lower case. so **Following** will be indexed as **following** that means searching "Following" won't give you result. For this `.toLowerCase()` will come to your rescue, just use this on your **sentence** and you should get results from search.

Also have a look at this [link](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Table_Word_Break_Property_Values) which specify Unicode Standard Annex #29 which is followed by [`StandardTokenizer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html). And from brief look at it, it looks like APOSTROPHE, QUOTATION MARK, FULL STOP, SMALL COMMA and many other characters under certain condition will be ignored while indexing.